# How do we combine multiple error strings in Golang?

Tags: go, error-handling

I am new to golang, my application needs to return multiple errors in a loop, later requires to be combined and returned as a single error string. I am not able to use the string functions to combine the error messages. What methods can be use to combine these errors into a single error before returning?

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func Servreturn() (err error) {

   err1 = fmt.Errorf("Something else occurred")
   err2 = fmt.Errorf("Something else occurred again")

   // concatenate both errors

   return err3

}
```

Comment: Not enought information. What the client do?  What your server do? A sample output.

Comment: A future version (Go 1.2x, for 2023) should provide a way to return a [slice/tree of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758530/6309).

Comment: downvote: concatenating the string messages is not that interesting, I'm looking for way to preserve the error objects and this question appears not to be about stacking or joining errors.

Comment: Go 1.20 adds multi-error wrapping. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645028/115363).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use the `strings.Join()` and `append()` function to acheive this slice.

[example: golang playgorund](https://play.golang.org/p/rpki9zcbzF)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    // create a slice for the errors
    var errstrings []string 

    // first error
    err1 := fmt.Errorf("First error:server error")
    errstrings = append(errstrings, err1.Error())

    // do something 
    err2 := fmt.Errorf("Second error:%s", syscall.ENOPKG.Error())
    errstrings = append(errstrings, err2.Error())

    // do something else
    err3 := fmt.Errorf("Third error:%s", syscall.ENOTCONN.Error())
    errstrings = append(errstrings, err3.Error())

    // combine and print all the error
    fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf(strings.Join(errstrings, "\n")))


}
```

This would output a single string which you can send back to the client.

```
First error:server1 
Second error:Package not installed 
Third error:Socket is not connected
```

hope this helps!

Comment: You can now use `errors.Join` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645028/115363

Answer (score 108):

UPDATE for Go 1.20:

As of [Go version 1.20](https://go.dev/blog/go1.20) you can [join errors](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#errors) with the new `errors.Join` [function](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#example-Join) (`nil` errors are ignored):

```
err = errors.Join(err, nil, err2, err3)
```

[Playground Example for errors.Join](https://go.dev/play/p/9WZaQCD-WOC)

Also, the `fmt.Errorf` function now supports wrapping multiple errors with multiple `%w` format verbs:

```
err := fmt.Errorf("%w; %w; %w", err, err2, err3)
```

[Playground Example for fmt.Errorf](https://go.dev/play/p/UpiGXBpCda0)

---

UPDATE for Go 1.13:

As of [Go version 1.13](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13), the language's [errors package](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) now supports [error wrapping](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#error_wrapping) directly.

You can wrap an error by using the `%w` verb in `fmt.Errorf`:

```
err := errors.New("Original error")
err = fmt.Errorf("%w; Second error", err)
```

Use [Unwrap](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Unwrap) to remove the last error added, and return what remains: `previousErrors := errors.Unwrap(err)`

[Playground Example for errors.Unwrap](https://play.golang.org/p/nqNrM8qOvST)

Two more functions, [errors.Is](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) and [errors.As](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#As) provide ways to check for and retrieve a specific type of error.

[Playground Example for errors.As and errors.Is](https://play.golang.org/p/NL_MiNC31o6)

---

Dave Cheney's excellent `errors` package (https://github.com/pkg/errors) include a `Wrap` function for this purpose:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/pkg/errors"

func main() {
        err := errors.New("error")
        err = errors.Wrap(err, "open failed")
        err = errors.Wrap(err, "read config failed")

        fmt.Println(err) // "read config failed: open failed: error"
}
```

This also allows additional functionality, such as unpacking the cause of the error:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/pkg/errors"

func main() {
    err := errors.New("original error")
    err = errors.Wrap(err, "now this")

    fmt.Println(errors.Cause(err)) // "original error"
}
```

As well as the option to output a stack trace when specifying `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)`.

You can find additional information about the package on his blog: [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully) and [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/06/12/stack-traces-and-the-errors-package).

Comment: Wrapping is not for a multiple errors. It is for wrapping ONE error with more context.

Comment: @dolmen can you provide a citation on that assertion?

Comment: @PauloNeves So far 17 persons approved my comment.

Comment: @dolmen what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Paulo: @dolmen is asserting that error wrapping is most intuitive when used like `InnerException`s in other languages. a wrapped error is not a list of (sibling) errors, but a chain of (parent-child) errors. there's nothing that stops you from using it like a list, but IMO it is counterintuitive.

Comment: Go 1.20 supports this natively with errors.Join. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645028/115363

Comment: Is there any impact on the fact, that errors.Join adds newlines? I usually do the fmt.Errorf("%w; %w") stuff, but think Join is the better syntax. Having it a one liner is better for fts logs though (thats an entirely subjective statement).

Answer (score 29):

String functions don't work on errors because error is really an interface that implements the function Error() string.

You can use string functions on err1.Error() and err2.Error()
but not on the "err1" reference itself.

Some errors are structs, like the ones you get from database drivers.

So there's no natural way to use string functions on errors since they may not actually be strings underneath.

As for combining two errors:

Easy, just use fmt.Errorf again.

```
fmt.Errorf("Combined error: %v %v", err1, err2)
```

Alternatively:

```
errors.New(err1.Error() + err2.Error())
```

Comment: Any other ways other than using fmt.Errorf(), why cant I use the string function ?

Comment: Sure. Depends on what you really mean by "combining". String concatenation is done using the `+` operator. Or you might store them individually in a slice, `append()`-ing values to it. *This* question suggests you should work yourself through a Go tutorial and get a book on it.

Comment: @GregPetr Potentially another clean way to do this is to have your own `CombinedError` struct that takes a list of errors as a field and implements the `Error() string` method and do what you want, whether its concatenating strings or whatsoever.

Answer (score 13):

To expand on what @WillC had mentioned in a comment it is possible to define your own `error` type as `error` is an interface type. Any type that implements a `Error() string` function implements the `error` interface. Therefore, you could create a `CollectionError` which aggregates errors and returns a concatenated error string.

```
type ErrorCollector []error

func (c *ErrorCollector) Collect(e error) { *c = append(*c, e) }

func (c *ErrorCollector) Error() (err string) {
    err = "Collected errors:\n"
    for i, e := range *c {
        err += fmt.Sprintf("\tError %d: %s\n", i, e.Error())
    }

    return err
}
```

This provides a collection function that appends a given `error` to a slice. Upon calling `Error() string` it iterates over the slice and creates a concatenated error string.

```
func main() {
    collector := new(ErrorCollector)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
         collector.Collect(errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("%d Error", i)))
    }

    fmt.Println(collector)
}
```

There is a great [golang.org blog post](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) going over errors in more detail. A full example of the example is available on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eztQmlaleB).

Comment: thanks, your example was very useful. I will try this out and get back.

Comment: @BenCampbell Is there a reason for the method receiver to be a pointer here?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. On the off chance one might add a nil error, the Error() function should do a nil check on the collected errors. And if one accesses by just index and not index + value, need to deference cast the error array before the index access. Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/h9F5WhcQ5Bs

Comment: @Rakesh No. `func (c *ErrorCollector) Error() (err string)` should be `func (c ErrorCollector) Error() (err string)`.

Comment: You don’t need to, but it would violate convention to have some methods be pointer receivers and some to be value receivers. Collect needs to be a pointer receiver.

Answer (score 13):

As of Go 1.20, we'll be able to wrap multiple errors using [errors.Join](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/432898/11/src/errors/join.go).

> See [this proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53435) for more details.

#### First Option

You can print the errors; they will be separated by a newline character when you do that.

```golang
var (
    ErrIncorrectUsername = errors.New("incorrect username")
    ErrIncorrectPassword = errors.New("incorrect password")
)

func main() {
    err := validate("ruster", "4321")
    // You can print multi-line errors
    // Each will be separated by a newline character (\n).
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        // incorrect username
        // incorrect password
    }
}

func validate(username, password string) error {
    var errs []error

    // errors.Join the errors into a single error
    if username != "gopher" {
        errs = append(errs, ErrIncorrectUsername)
    }
    if password != "1234" {
        errs = append(errs, ErrIncorrectPassword)
    }

    // Join returns a single `error`.
    // Underlying, the error contains all the errors we add.
    return errors.Join(errs...)
}
```

#### Second Option

`errors.Join` returns an `error` that contains each error you add. So you can use [errors.Is](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) and [errors.As](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As) to check for individual errors for finer granularity.

```golang
// ...
func main() {
    err := validate("ruster", "4321")
    // You can detect each one:
    if errors.Is(err, ErrIncorrectUsername) {
        // handle the error here
    }
    // Or detect the other one:
    if errors.Is(err, ErrIncorrectPassword) {
        // handle the error here
    }
}

func validate(username, password string) error {
    // ...
}
```

Note: This naive `validate` example is here to convey the idea. Instead of chaining errors, think errors like a tree. `Join` allows you to do that when combined with other `Join`s.

---

[Run both on Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/py0Jg40u_Fi?v=gotip).

Answer (score 11):

Uber has a [multierr](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/uber-go/multierr?tab=doc) package for this use case:

```golang
return multierr.Combine(err1, err2)
```

Comment: As of Go 1.20, it is natively supported: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645028/115363.

Answer (score 8):

People may be interested in https://github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror which describes itself as "A Go (golang) package for representing a list of errors as a single error.".

Comment: It comes with MPL license which requires you to disclose the source code

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work well for me (space separated errors):

1. Put all your errors in a error slice/list/array, ie: var errors [] error
2. fmt.Sprintf("%s", errors)

```
    var errors []error
    errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("error 1"))
    errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("error 2"))
    errors = append(errors, fmt.Errorf("and yet another error"))
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s", errors)
    fmt.Println(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes i need the way to detect if there some  error in the chain. the standard way, provided with https://pkg.go.dev/errors is pretty convenient:

```
someErr:=errors.New("my error")
fmt.Errorf("can't process request: %w",someErr) 
...
err:=f()
if errors.Is(err,someErr){...}
```

But it could be applied only in the case of detection of the last error in the chain. You can't wrap someErr1 and then someErr2 and then get true from both of checks: errors.Is(err,someErr1) and errors.Is(err,someErr2)

I solved this problem with following type:

```
func NewJoinedErrors(err1 error, err2 error) JoinedErrors {
    return JoinedErrors{err1: err1, err2: err2}
}

type JoinedErrors struct {
    err1 error
    err2 error
}

func (e JoinedErrors) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", e.err1, e.err2)
}

func (e JoinedErrors) Unwrap() error {
    return e.err2
}

func (e JoinedErrors) Is(target error) bool {
    return errors.Is(e.err1, target)
}
```

It uses the fact, that

> An error is considered to match a target if it is equal to that target
> or if it implements a method Is(error) bool such that Is(target)
> returns true.

So you can join two errors and get positive result on both checks:

```
someErr1:=errors.New("my error 1")
someErr2:=errors.New("my error 2")
err:=NewJoinedErrors(someErr1, someErr2)
// this will be true because 
// (e JoinedErrors) Is(target error) 
// will return true 
if errors.Is(err, someErr1){...}
// this will be true because 
// (e JoinedErrors) Unwrap() error 
// will return err2 
if errors.Is(err, someErr2){...}
```

you can check it out here: https://play.golang.org/p/W7NGyfvr0v_N

Answer (score 0):

```
func condenseErrors(errs []error) error {
    switch len(errs) {
    case 0:
        return nil
    case 1:
        return errs[0]
    }
    err := errs[0]
    for _, e := range errs[1:] {
        err = errors.Wrap(err, e.Error())
    }
    return err
}
```

Comment: pay attention that if first error is nil e.g [nil, error1, error2, error3] you code will return nil because of the Wrap implementation 
```
func Wrap(err error, message string) error {
 if err == nil {
  return nil
 }
 err = &withMessage{
  cause: err,
  msg:   message,
 }
 return &withStack{
  err,
  callers(),
 }
}
```

Comment: Good point. This assumes that errs passed to the function are not nil.

Answer (score -1):

Use this function:

```
func JoinErrs(errs ...error) error {
    var joinErrsR func(string, int, ...error) error
    joinErrsR = func(soFar string, count int, errs ...error) error {
        if len(errs) == 0 {
            if count == 0 {
                return nil
            }
            return fmt.Errorf(soFar)
        }
        current := errs[0]
        next := errs[1:]
        if current == nil {
            return joinErrsR(soFar, count, next...)
        }
        count++
        if count == 1 {
            return joinErrsR(fmt.Sprintf("%s", current), count, next...)
        } else if count == 2 {
            return joinErrsR(fmt.Sprintf("1: %s\n2: %s", soFar, current), count, next...)
        }
        return joinErrsR(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n%d: %s", soFar, count, current), count, next...)
    }
    return joinErrsR("", 0, errs...)
}
```

It will give you nil when all errors are nil, will give you the same error when just one non-nil error, will give you numbered list of non-nil errors when multiple non-nil errors

Try it out here: https://play.golang.org/p/WttztCr-xHG